Can't transfer data from React form to DATA.txt using Express
I try many things but it always gives me same error. I tried to change file path but it was pointless
Currently my project looks like this:{nodemodules,public,scr(there are all files including App.jsx),DATA.txt,server.js}
Here is my error:
App.jsx:33 Error submitting form:  AxiosErrorcode: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Request failed with status code 404"name: "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…\n<body>\n<pre>Cannot POST /</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}stack: "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42609:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41269:66)\n    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41770:41)\n    at async handleSubmit (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50:7)"[[Prototype]]: Error) *

server.js:
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const appData = req.body;
  fs.appendFile("data.txt", JSON.stringify(appData) + "\n", (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
  res.send("Data has been successfully submitted!");
});

app.listen(PORT);

App.jsx:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
    const [appData, setAppData] = useState({
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        email: '',
        phoneNumber: '',
        country: '',
        paymentType: ''
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setAppData({ ...appData, [name]: value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            await axios.post('/', appData);
            alert('Form submitted successfully!');
            setAppData({
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                phoneNumber: '',
                country: '',
                paymentType: ''
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting form: ', error);
            alert('Error submitting form. Please try again.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" value={appData.firstName} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="First Name" required /><br />
            <input type="text" name="lastName" value={appData.lastName} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Last Name" required /><br />
            <input type="email" name="email" value={appData.email} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Email" required /><br />
            <input type="tel" name="phoneNumber" value={appData.phoneNumber} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Phone Number" required /><br />
            <input type="text" name="country" value={appData.country} onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Country" required /><br />
            <select name="paymentType" value={appData.paymentType} onChange={handleChange} required>
                <option value="">Select Payment Type</option>
                <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
                <option value="PayPal">PayPal</option>
                <option value="Bank Transfer">Bank Transfer</option>
            </select><br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default App;



You are receiving 404 (Not Found). On what ports React app, express app are running? Two apps cant run on the same port. Please try axios.post("http://localhost:3000/", appData)

my package.json was like this (
"start": "concurrently "npm run start-server" "npm run start-client"",
"start-server": "PORT=7000 node server.js",
"start-client": "react-scripts start",) but later i remove start-server and only left start-client also i changed sever port to port=3000

First, can you check if the server and frontend are running on the same port? This error might have been caused by trying to call an API that doesn't exist.

"start": "concurrently "npm run start-server" "npm run start-client"",
"start-server": "PORT=7000 node server.js",
"start-client": "react-scripts start", here is my current package.json
